# my app reject because of something about app updating

Tags: ios, iphone

the reason:“
your app includes an update or alerts the user to update the app. to avoid
user confusion,app version updates muse utilize the iOS built-in update mechanism
”

my app is rejected，the reason is in the picture above.
i don‘t know what is the iOS build－in update mechanism，could anyone tell me about that in detail.3q

Comment: Do you have code which prompts the user to upgrade? Is so Apple is asking you remove it as iOS itself has such a capabilities build into the AppStore.app

Comment: yes， there is a button in my codes,apple let me remove it ,but i have develop some apps,apple never reject it about this reason before,and i found there are many apps  checking update in their app,  why ?please. thank u very much

Comment: Ok Apple requires you remove it in order to accept your app...

Comment: Nothing specifically that I'm aware of but many of the Apple guidelines are fairly broad. See https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-interface

Comment: Maybe they just found the prompt in your app?

Comment: yeah， that is. last one to make sure.
what should i do is remove it and then do nothing?  is that necessary to   make other setting?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue today, and I just follow the Review Team's instruction: **remove the update feature from your app.**

Comment: maybe it is stricter than before on this issue.